# Globally permit a strong param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

Is there a way to permit a param for all actions? The app I'm working on has a feature flag system and I'd like feature flags to be overridable via query string parameters (to aid testing). I've added something like the following to the `application_controller`:

```
before_action :apply_feature_flag_overrides

def apply_feature_flag_overrides
  overrides = params.permit![:feature_flags]
  current_user.feature_flag_overrides = overrides
end
```

This is working fine for actions that don't make use of params, but when an action does I get an error like:

```
ActionController::UnpermittedParameters at /upcoming_posts
found unpermitted parameter: :feature_flags
```

It appears that `params.permit` or `params.require` is expected to only be called once for any given action. Is that correct? Is there a way to globally white list a set of params for a cross cutting concern like this? I could update every call to `params` to also include `:feature_flags` but that's going to be error prone and repetitive.

Comment: You may want to delete it from the `params` once you've made use of it. That way it won't interfere with other checks.

Comment: Nice! That ended up working. I slightly tweaked my code to use `params.to_unsafe_h[:feature_flags]` to get the flags and then, based on your suggestion, I cleaned them up with: `params.reject! { |key| key == "feature_flags" }`. Do you want to post as an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: I think you figured out the details, so it's worth adding a self-answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @tadman's comment about removing the param once used I got this working. The updated code looks like:

```
before_action :apply_feature_flag_overrides

def apply_feature_flag_overrides
  overrides = params.to_unsafe_h[:feature_flags]
  current_user.feature_flag_overrides = overrides
  params.reject! { |key| key == "feature_flags" }
end
```